# Downgrade Flutter to Meet Kotlin Version

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have upgraded Flutter version to the latest release but now some binaries seem to be incompatible with my Android project configuration (see console snippet below). Is there a way to revert the Flutter upgrade to match the required Kotlin binaries?

```
e: /home/lkeon/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers_android-1.1.1/android/src/main/kotlin/xyz/luan/audioplayers/source/UrlSource.kt: (47, 30): 
Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

I have also tried to upgrade Kotlin following the console output below, but unsuccessfully.

```
┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update /home/lkeon/Documents/Repos/moretini-invaders/android/build.gradle:                   │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: what exactly didn't work when upgrading the kotlin version? That would be my preferred way of fixing this version conflict since you can only delay updating for so long anyways. In case you misunderstood the instructions, you change from what should currently read `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1''` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'` (latest) or `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'` (min required in your case). Android Studio should also show you notifications when you open a project that can be updated with new tools and so on and should be able to do all that without manually editing those files

Comment: Thanks for help, it turned out that `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` was not up to date.